# Garage Door weather stripping replacement -- single groove

Tags: garage, weatherstripping

My weather stripping came off, is broken, and the bottom of the garage door is slick with a single groove in the bottom. What type of weather stripping should I use? I've seen options online that fit into a track on the bottom, but nothing that I can tell fits on my door.

[image: Garage Door]

Edit:
So this won't work  -- but looked close. I don't have a slot on the bottom. Maybe I need to get one. It is from http://www.garagedoorstuff.com/product/clopay-garage-door-weather-seal/

The old seal looks like this:

[image]

But I would like a better solution that doesn't fall off so easily.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the way to go [link to clopay stripping](http://www.garagedoorstuff.com/product/clopay-garage-door-weather-seal/) It looks right, but I'm not sure how to get it to stick.

Comment: Weather stripping of the type you show is normally fed into the slot at one end of the door and pulled across. The "T" at the top rides in the slot and is wide enough not to pull out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I had that type of bottom on one of my other garage doors. The big center slot was meant for a compression fit seal that I couldn't find a replacement for.

I ended up filling that slot with [this being modified](http://www.homedepot.com/p/MD-Building-Products-1-5-8-in-x-18-ft-Aluminum-and-Vinyl-Garage-Door-Bottom-87668/100119584). I cut the 2 tracks free, stacked them & screwed them into the top of the big slot to then put in the Clopay type single T-end bulb. A pain to setup, but totally worth it for the ease of replacement twice before I moved out of the house.

However, your old seal's design is fine & just needs to be screwed-in to the door's face every 3-feet to be fully secure & still easy to replace. Something [like this](http://www.homedepot.com/p/L-I-F-Industries-Door-U-Bottom-Seal-for-Doors-up-to-36-in-Wide-U36/202510612) is what you'd be doing with aluminum or stainless steel screws through the shoulder that wraps up the door.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by stacking the tracks. Why did you need to do that?

Comment: Ah, I see the screw is in the middle, so some surface needs to be on the bottom. Maybe I should put a thin composite in there.

Comment: I stacked them to get me close to flush so the gasket could actually flatten-out & conform to any concrete variations. I had a low clearance door & if I added the 1/4" to the door bottom I got an air leak up top. It worked very well. And yep, you could back the track with anything weather durable. I couldn't find just the T-track nor even a full set of T-track & T-end Gasket. So, I improvised at a pretty steep cost, but it lasted over 20-years & gasket replacements were a cheap breeze.